# How to set textbox by value which get from each row of tablix?

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, rdl

If Datasource has 4 rows like these

```
 ___Item_____
     AA
     BB
     CC
     DD
```

If I make 10 textboxes
I need to input 4 value (AA,BB,CC and DD) to textboxes.
if some textbox isn't value, It will show (***)
like below .

[image]

1st row put to the first textbox.

2nd row put to the  second textbox.

3rd row put to the  third textbox.

4th row put to the  fourth textbox.

and other put (***) because of Datasource has only 4 rows.

I mean I need to show free layout .I not mean horizontal tablix .
[image]

Comment: Are you able to edit the underlying SQL?  And will it always be 10 Columns?

Comment: Do you mean display them via horizontal tablix? But I need to show them in textboxes. So I need to know ,How to refer to each row of tablix?

Comment: Well as a horizontal tablix is one option.  It is also possible just as textboxes.  Both of these would be assisted by assigning an index to the rows returned, if it possible to edit the SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you wish to display the data in a fixed amount of textboxes and your dataset only has a single column, you shouldn't really try to fill the report dynamically. Instead of using an undefined datasource you could simply format the data and pass it as a list of parameters to the report.

```
ReportParameter[] reportParameters = new ReportParameter[10];
for (int i = 0; i < reportParameters.Length; i++)
{
   reportParameters[i] = new ReportParameter(string.Format("pParam{0}", i),
        (i < myDataSource.Count) ? myDataSource[i] : "***");
}

myViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters);
```

Then simply make sure you have parameters defined for the ones you are trying to display (e.g. pParam0 , pParam1, ... , pParam9) and add those in the wanted textboxes.